# Testing if a void* passed into a function is either a shared_ptr or a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, void-pointers, reinterpret-cast

I am working on creating a function for a class and the parameter is declared as a void* however within the function I need to test if this void* is either a shared_ptr or unique_ptr is there a way to test for this type of situation?

This is what I am working with so far; my class is a template type and does not store any member variables. It has a default constructor and it can also be constructed by passing in either a `shared_ptr<Type>` or an `unique_ptr<Type>` and it is has multiple `allocate()` functions where they do the same type of work.

```
#ifndef ALLOCATOR_H
#define ALLOCATOR_H

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<class Type>
class Allocator {
public:
    Allocator(){}
    Allocator( Type type, void* pPtr );
    Allocator( std::shared_ptr<Type>& pType );
    Allocator( std::unique_ptr<Type>& pType );
    // ~Allocator(); // Default Okay

    void allocate( std::shared_ptr<Type>& pType );
    void allocate( std::unique_ptr<Type>& pType );
    void allocate( Type type, void* pPtr );

private:
    Allocator( const Allocator& c ); // Not Implemented
    Allocator& operator=( const Allocator& c ); // Not Implemented

}; // Allocator

#include "Allocator.inl"

#endif // ALLOCATOR_H
```

My `*.cpp` file only has `#include "Allocator.h"` since all of the implementations are within my `*.inl` file.

My two constructors: `Allocator( std::shared_ptr<Type>& pType );` & `Allocator( std::unique_ptr<Type>& pType );` along with both matching `allocate()` functions work fine. The constructor `Allocator( Type type, void* pPtr );` and its matching function is where I am having trouble.

The constructor itself is straight forward since all it does is invoke the matching function passing to it the variables.

```
template<class Type>
Allocator<Type>::Allocator( Type type, void* pPtr ) {
    allocate( type, eType, pPtr );
}
```

It is within the function implementation that I am struggling.

```
template<class Type>
void Allocator<Type>::allocate( Type type, void* pData ) {
    if ( pData == reinterpret_cast<void*>( std::shared_ptr<Type ) ) {
        std::shared_ptr<Type> pShared;
        pShared.reset( new Type( type ) );
        pData = reinterpret_cast<void*>( pShared );

    } else if ( pData == reinterpret_cast<void*>( std::unique_ptr<Type ) ) {
        std::unique_ptr<Type> pUnique;
        pUnique.reset( new Type( type ) );
        pData = reinterpret_cast<void*>( pUnique );

    } else {
        std::cout << "Error invalid pointer type passed in << std::endl
                  << "must be either a std::shared_ptr<Type> << std::endl
                  << "or a std::unique_ptr<Type> << std::endl;
    }            
}
```

Other than checking to see if the `void*` passed in is either a `std::shared_ptr<Type>` or a `std::unique_ptr<Type>`the other questions I may have would be, is my use of `reinterpret_cast<void*>` the correct way to convert a smart pointer to a void pointer and if not how can this be achieved?

Comment: Weird stuff. What's the need for it?

Comment: There is no basic need, it was just a self desired exercise to strengthen my skills with templates. I thought it would be a nice utility type class where you can instantiate it with a desired type and then call its member function to create either a shared_ptr or unique_ptr of that type, or do the same by using its constructors.

Comment: You simply can't do that, a void pointer doesn't carry any type information with it, unless you can imply it using a reasonable `reinterpret_cast`, where you exactly know how to interpret the memory layout pointed to with the `void*` pointer.

Comment: Is your `void*` pointing at a shared/unique ptr? Or is it pointing are what the share/unique ptr points at too? Or are you really trying to reinterpret the bytes of a shared/unique ptr as a `void*`? If the third possibility (as your other code implies), then I think you're doomed. Among other problems, there's no guarantee that the size of a void pointer is the same as the size of a shared/unique pointer (and I believe shared_ptr will probably never be the same size).

Comment: The method doesn't know if the user is going to pass in a shared_ptr or a unique_ptr when the function is called or invoked. I was using void* in its declaration, but when the function is being used one needs to pass in one or the other.

Comment: At one point I was thinking about removing the template type from the class itself and just having the functions themselves being function templates. Doing it this way would require two separate functions.

Comment: This was a self desired exercise to strengthen my skills with templates and thought that this might be a handy utility class to quickly create shared & unique ptrs of a specific type on the fly.

Comment: The class you've shown already has overloads for shared_ptr and unique_ptr... so I'm missing why the `void*` overload even needs to worry about them. Are you trying to compress the implementations of `allocate` into one function (as per Remy's answer)? If so, that just seems to be over-complicating what should be a couple simple separate overloads. Otherwise, are you calling the class in a way that the current `std::shared_ptr<Type>&` and `std::unique_ptr<Type>&` overloads don't already handle? If so, then show what you're really trying to achieve on the outside.

Comment: With everyone's feed back I was able to revamp this class, I provided it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `void*` pointer does not carry any type information.  What you need to do is pass around an additional value along with the `void*` to specify what the `void*` points to, and then you can type-cast it accordingly.

```
#ifndef ALLOCATOR_H
#define ALLOCATOR_H

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<class Type>
class Allocator {
public:
    enum AllocateType { eSharedPtr, eUniquePtr };

    Allocator() {}
    Allocator( Type type, std::shared_ptr<Type>& pData );
    Allocator( Type type, std::unique_ptr<Type>& pData );
    // ~Allocator(); // Default Okay

    void allocate( Type type, std::shared_ptr<Type>& pData );
    void allocate( Type type, std::unique_ptr<Type>& pData );

private:
    Allocator( const Allocator& c ); // Not Implemented
    Allocator& operator=( const Allocator& c ); // Not Implemented

    void allocate( Type type, AllocateType eDataType, void* pData );

}; // Allocator

#include "Allocator.inl"

#endif // ALLOCATOR_H
```

```
template<class Type>
Allocator<Type>::Allocator( Type type, std::shared_ptr<Type>& pData ) {
    allocate( type, pData );
}

template<class Type>
Allocator<Type>::Allocator( Type type, std::unique_ptr<Type>& pData ) {
    allocate( type, pData );
}

template<class Type>
void Allocator<Type>::allocate( Type type, std::shared_ptr<Type>& pData ) {
    allocate( type, eSharedPtr, &pData );
}

template<class Type>
void Allocator<Type>::allocate( Type type, std::unique_ptr<Type>& pData ) {
    allocate( type, eUniquePtr, &pData );
}

template<class Type>
void Allocator<Type>::allocate( Type type, AllocateType eDataType, void* pData ) {
    switch (eDataType) {
        case eSharedPtr: {
            static_cast<std::shared<Type>*>(pData)->reset( new Type( type ) );
            break;
        }
        case eUniquePtr: {
            static_cast<std::unique_ptr<Type>*>(pData)->reset( new Type( type ) );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In which case, I wouldn't even bother trying to funnel everything through a single function to begin with:

```
#ifndef ALLOCATOR_H
#define ALLOCATOR_H

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<class Type>
class Allocator {
public:
    Allocator() {}
    Allocator( Type type, std::shared_ptr<Type>& pData );
    Allocator( Type type, std::unique_ptr<Type>& pData );
    // ~Allocator(); // Default Okay

    void allocate( Type type, std::shared_ptr<Type>& pData );
    void allocate( Type type, std::unique_ptr<Type>& pData );

private:
    Allocator( const Allocator& c ); // Not Implemented
    Allocator& operator=( const Allocator& c ); // Not Implemented

}; // Allocator

#include "Allocator.inl"

#endif // ALLOCATOR_H
```

```
template<class Type>
Allocator<Type>::Allocator( Type type, std::shared_ptr<Type>& pData ) {
    allocate( type, pData );
}

template<class Type>
Allocator<Type>::Allocator( Type type, std::unique_ptr<Type>& pData ) {
    allocate( type, pData );
}

template<class Type>
void Allocator<Type>::allocate( Type type, std::shared_ptr<Type>& pData ) {
    pData.reset( new Type( type ) ) ;
}

template<class Type>
void Allocator<Type>::allocate( Type type, std::unique_ptr<Type>& pData ) {
    pData.reset( new Type( type ) );
}
```

Comment: This is what I was aiming for and thank you for the clarification. However I did notice that you are using a static_cast as opposed to a reinterpret_cast. However, since this class doesn't store any internal values and only has member functions. I kind of went a different route.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is meant to be used when casting between integers and pointers, or between unrelated pointer types. That does not really include `void*`, though.  You can `static_cast` from `void*` to any other pointer type (any pointer type can be directly assigned to a `void*` without using a cast at all).

Comment: Labeau Thank you for that information; I have used static_cast and dynamic_cast quite often, but I have not used reinterpret_cast all that much. Thank you for easily clarifying the main differences.

Comment: With everyone's feed back I was able to revamp this class, I provided it as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can't check to see what type a `void*` is. It's a `void*`. That's it. It's not like `boost::any` where it's craftily hiding some other type information. It's **just** `void*`. You can't check what type it came from. You can't test to see if it came from a specific type. You have zero information. Zip. Nada. Zilch. Void.

Comment: Well strange machine/compiler specific hacks (canaries and such) may be applicable. Though no standard way to do such, totally agreed.

Comment: I was thinking about that so if it is not possible to check to see if the pointer passed into the function is one type or another, how do I know which method to call? If one passes a shared_ptr versus a unique_ptr this is where I'm stuck. I was thinking about using a enum type to be specified, but if one uses a SHARED_PTR enum but an unique_ptr is passed in that would be a problem and vice versa.

Comment: @FrancisCugler You should actually pass the smart pointer - rather than a `void*`. Don't just drop the type information on the floor if you actually need it!

Comment: With everyone's feed back I was able to revamp this class, I provided it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After some consideration and knowing that this class does not store any member variables internally and only contains functions that do a specific task I went with a different approach. I do thank every one for their feedback and answers since they do give good valid answers to the basic questions in which I originally asked. This is what I was able to achieve from your advise. I removed the stipulation that this class itself is a template, I made the default constructor private. I made sure each function is a function template and made them static. Here is my new class:

**Allocator.h**

```
#ifndef ALLOCATOR_H
#define ALLOCATOR_H

#include <memory>

class Allocator {
public:
    template<class Type>
    inline static void allocate( std::shared_ptr<Type>& pShared, const Type& type = Type() );

    template<class Type>
    inline static void allocate( std::unique_ptr<Type>& pUnique, const Type& type = Type() );

private:
    Allocator();
    Allocator( const Allocator& c );
    Allocator& operator=( const Allocator& c );

}; // Allocator

#include "Allocator.inl"

#endif // Allocator
```

**Allocator.cpp**

```
#include "Allocator.h"
```

**Allocator.inl**

```
template<class Type>
inline void Allocator::allocate( std::shared_ptr<Type>& pShared, const Type& type ) {
    pShared.reset( new Type( type ) );  
}

template<class Type>
inline void Allocator::allocate( std::unique_ptr<Type>& pUnique, const Type& type ) {
    pUnique.reset( new Type( type ) );
}
```

This makes using this class simple.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

#include "Allocator.h"

class A {
private:
    int m_a;
public:
    explicit A( int a = 0 ) : m_a( a ) {}
    A( const A& a ) { this->m_a = a.m_a; }

    int  getA() const { return m_a; }
    void setA( int a ) { m_a = a; }
}; // A

int main() {

    // Creating Smart A Pointer Just From A Class Type
    std::shared_ptr<A> pShared;
    std::unique_ptr<A> pUnique;

    Allocator::allocate( pShared );
    Allocator::allocate( pUnique );

    std::cout << "Shared: " << pSharedA->getA() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Unique: " << pUniqueA->getA() << std::endl;

    pSharedA->setA( 4 );
    pUniqueA->setA( 5 );

    std::cout << "Shared: " << pSharedA->getA() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Unique: " << pUniqueA->getA() << std::endl;

    // Create A Smart Pointer From An Object Of Type In This Case A
    // This next sections does rely on the fact that Type in this case A, should have a copy constructor defined.

    A a1( 3 );
    std::shared_ptr<A> sharedA;
    std::unique_ptr<A> uniqueA;
    Allocator::allocate( sharedA, a1 );
    Allocator::allocate( uniqueA, a1 );

    std::cout << "Shared: " << sharedA->getA() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Unique: " << uniqueA->getA() << std::endl;

    sharedA->setA( 6 );
    uniqueA->setA( 7 );

    std::cout << "Shared: " << sharedA->getA() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Unique: " << uniqueA->getA() << std::endl;

    pSharedA.reset();
    pUniqueA.release();
    pUniqueA.reset();

    sharedA.reset();
    uniqueA.release();
    uniqueA.reset();

    std::cout << std::endl << "Press Any Key To Quit" << std::endl;
    _getch();

    return 0;

} // main
```

This also removes the need to do any type casting, comparisons etc, improving the efficiency of the work being done. I could of even taken this one step further by declaring all of these functions as inline.

**EDIT**

I took the advice of Remy Lebeau and removed two of the overloaded functions by adding in the `Type type` as a default parameter and also changed it to pass by const reference. I also made the functions inline.

Comment: You don't really need the extra 2 `allocate()` overloads that have `type` parameters. You can have 2 overloads total that have `type` parameters with default values for when not specified by the caller, eg: `static void allocate( std::shared_ptr<Type>& pShared, Type type = Type() ); ... Allocator::allocate( pShared ); ... Allocator::allocate( shared, a1 );`  You might also consider changing `Type type` to `const Type &type` to avoid unnecessary copies.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Very true; I wasn't thinking about that. I think I'll edit this answer to reflect your response.